# About nick your beer

Tags: idioms

> My Twitter listening parties are like gigs-but nobody nicks your beer.

What's "nicks your beer" here? I can't take it straight.

Source: https://amp.theguardian.com/music/2020/apr/10/tim-burgess-twitter-listening-parties?__twitter_impression=true

Dictionary definitions:

Nick:

Beer:

Comment: Please provide a clear source for your quote. The best way is make a link to the internet site, if possible.  Then make sure that you write down in your question the dictionary definitions for "nick" and "beer" that you are using.

Comment: The link: https://amp.theguardian.com/music/2020/apr/10/tim-burgess-twitter-listening-parties?__twitter_impression=true

Comment: I failed to work out their definitions here.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Now, you don't work out their definitions here.  You don't work out anything.  You get your favourite dictionary (online or paper) and you look up the words, and you copy the definition into the question.  Then you say why you can't understand the meaning of the phrase. :-)  This is called "prior research".  It makes your question better.  Note that you can [edit] your own question.  Then I don't need to edit your question for you.

Answer (score 1):

In British English *to nick* is to steal or take away illegitimately. While one is playing music at a job or en*gag*ement [hence gig] you are not keeping an eye on your drink. As such it may be lost to those thirsty fans. Twitter gigs do not have this problem.